# Jquery - pull new data with $_GET variables each time a div is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm going to do my best explaining this, as I'm fumbling around a bit as it's my first time doing anything like this.

At the beginning of my page I call a function that returns 3 recipe's, I then create variables and assign each with a recipe id:

```
$meal = builder::buildMealPlan(1200,0,0,0,3);

$id1 = $meal[0][id];
$id2 = $meal[1][id];
$id3 = $meal[2][id];
```

So I now know the id's of the 3 recipe's that have been chosen by the function, I then display these 3 recipe's in 3 div's:

```
<div id="meal1"><h2><? print_r($meal[0]); ?></h2></div>
<div id="meal2"><h2><? print_r($meal[1]); ?></h2></div>
<div id="meal3"><h2><? print_r($meal[2]); ?></h2></div>
```

When any of these div's are clicked it means you don't like that recipe and want a different one, it calls a page with 4 parameters (id1,id2,id3,clicked), basically telling it the 3 recipe's that are currently displayed as well as which one was clicked, so I can find another combination of recipes with 2 of the same id's, as well as the new one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#meal1").click(function(){
  $.get("testing-01.php?id1=<?echo $id1;?  >&id2=<?echo $id2;?>&id3=<?echo $id3;?>&clicked=1", function(result){
    $("#meal1").html(result);
});
```

});

This works great, a proper recipe is selected and the div is refreshed with the new recipe, however my problem is now, if you click any of the div's again, it refreshes with the same recipe over and over again, because my php variables ($id1, $id2, $id3) are always the same value, since the page is never reloaded.

My question: How can I set a javascript variable with the result of my onclick event? Right now the on click event replaces the div with data from:

```
$.get("testing-01.php?id1=<?echo $id1;?  >&id2=<?echo $id2;?>&id3=<?echo $id3;?>&clicked=1
```

However I need to somehow update the variables that I'm sending in the above statement with new values each time a div is clicked.

If you've read this far, thanks, if I've left important/obvious things out please just let me know and I'll add it in.

EDIT: Ok, I've got it outputting JSON now:

```
  {"mealnumber":1,"id":"69","title":"Protein Packed Meatloaf","description":"This meatloaf is packed with protein to help your muscles grow.","cookingtime":"00:25 ","preptime":"00:10 ","servings":"4.00","rating":"0.000","calories_ps":"205.00","carbohydrate_ps":"7.70","protein_ps":"20.55","fat_ps":"9.64"}
```

My JS code to try and show that I'm at least reading it correctly:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#meal1").click(function(){

     $.getJSON("testing-01.php?id1="+id1+"&id2="+id2+"&id3="+id3+"&clicked=1",      function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
        console.log(item.id);
        alert(item.id);
        });
    });
    });
```

});

However nothing is logged or alerted when I click the div... am I missing something obvious here? I can see in the console that it's calling to the correct page, if I copy and paste the URL I get the json code I pasted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure i understand all you need, but i guess you need to change this 3 ID's in get method.

You could make some simple javascript object that store 3 id's, and rewrite it on success ajax... Buy you need better repsonse then just html... Try json...

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#meal1").click(function(){
      $.get("testing-01.php?id1="+SomeJavascriptObject.id1"&id2="+SomeJavascriptObject.id2"&id3="+SomeJavascriptObject.id3"&clicked=1", function(result){

       SomeJavascriptObject.id1 =result.returnedID1;
 SomeJavascriptObject.id2 = result.returnedID2;
 SomeJavascriptObject.id3 = result.returnedID3;
        $("#meal1").html(result.html);
    });
```

[Maybe this can help you.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Comment: Wow, seeing it laid out like this, it makes it seem so obvious.

I'll change it to output in JSON and try what you've suggested above and report back here, thanks!

Comment: I've edited my original post, I've tried switching to JSON, I feel like I'm close, but missing something obvious :(

Thanks a bunch for any help

Comment: Im glad i can help... Anytime ;)